# How can I create a DLNA server application in Android?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, dlna

I am looking to add DLNA server capabilities of one of my current applications (for movie management), and I've tried to do some searching for any documentation on it, but so far I've only found a project called Cling, which should support Android. I have yet to try it out, so if anyone has any comments on the project, I'd be really happy.

I'd also love if anyone had some more documentation on adding DLNA server functionality to an Android application. I know there are quite a few applications that make use of this, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should search for some Linux libraries that implement DLNA. This will be the easiest way to go. DLNA specification cost lots of money and implementation and tests could not be trivial.
Of  course you should check license of available software, because some of them could have restrictions.

Check the links from this wiki http://elinux.org/DLNA_Open_Source_Projects

Answer (score 1):

I use [this code](https://code.google.com/p/wireme/source/browse/src/com/wireme/?r=b0db9c440b168cd50ca74fb2bec86feea587d4d9#wireme%2Fmediaserver) for my project.